# Regex to remove everything before and then split

Tags: regex, perl

I basically need to come up with a regex to give me all the KB numbers from the list below. I think i need to strip up to the first [ then split on commas and then remove the [xx]: from each split.

can someone point me in the right direction. I'm working in perl btw.

"194 Hotfix(s) Installed.,[01]: 982861,[02]: KB2592687,[03]: KB2425227,[04]: KB2484033,[05]: KB2488113,[06]: KB2492386,[07]: KB2503665,[08]: KB2505438,[09]: KB2506014,[10]: KB2506212,[11]: KB2506928,[12]: KB2507618,[13]: KB2509553,[14]: KB2510531,[15]: KB2511250,[16]: KB2511455,[17]: KB2515325,[18]: KB2518869,[19]: KB2522422,[20]: KB2529073,[21]: KB2533552,[22]: KB2536275,[23]: KB2536276,[24]: KB2539635,[25]: KB2541014,[26]: KB2544893,[27]: KB2545698,[28]: KB2547666,[29]: KB2552343,[30]: KB2556532,[31]: KB2560656,[32]: KB2563227,[33]: KB2564958,[34]: KB2567680,[35]: KB2570947,[36]: KB2572077,[37]: KB2574819,[38]: KB2584146,[39]: KB2585542,[40]: KB2588516,[41]: KB2603229,[42]: KB2604115,[43]: KB2607047,[44]: KB2607576,[45]: KB2608658,[46]: KB2618444,[47]: KB2618451,[48]: KB2620704,[49]: KB2620712,[50]: KB2621146,[51]: KB2621440,[52]: KB2631813,[53]: KB2633873,[54]: KB2633952,[55]: KB2636573,[56]: KB2639308,[57]: KB2639417,[58]: KB2640148,[59]: KB2641653,[60]: KB2641690,[61]: KB2643719,[62]: KB2644615,[63]: KB2645640,[64]: KB2647516,[65]: KB2647518,[66]: KB2647753,[67]: KB2653956,[68]: KB2654428,[69]: KB2655992,[70]: KB2656356,[71]: KB2656373,[72]: KB2656411,[73]: KB2658846,[74]: KB2659262,[75]: KB2660075,[76]: KB2660465,[77]: KB2661254,[78]: KB2665364,[79]: KB2667402,[80]: KB2675157,[81]: KB2676562,[82]: KB2677070,[83]: KB2679255,[84]: KB2685811,[85]: KB2685813,[86]: KB2685939,[87]: KB2686831,[88]: KB2688338,[89]: KB2690533,[90]: KB2691442,[91]: KB2695962,[92]: KB2698365,[93]: KB2699779,[94]: KB2699988,[95]: KB2705219,[96]: KB2709162,[97]: KB2709630,[98]: KB2709715,[99]: KB2709981,[100]: KB2712808,[101]: KB2718523,[102]: KB2718704,[103]: KB2719177,[104]: KB2719857,[105]: KB2719985,[106]: KB2722913,[107]: KB2724197,[108]: KB2726535,[109]: KB2729094,[110]: KB2729452,[111]: KB2731771,[112]: KB2731847,[113]: KB2732059,[114]: KB2735855,[115]: KB2736233,[116]: KB2736422,[117]: KB2739159,[118]: KB2741355,[119]: KB2742599,[120]: KB2743555,[121]: KB2744842,[122]: KB2749655,[123]: KB2750841,[124]: KB2753842,[125]: KB2756822,[126]: KB2756921,[127]: KB2757638,[128]: KB2758857,[129]: KB2761217,[130]: KB2761226,[131]: KB2761451,[132]: KB2761465,[133]: KB2762895,[134]: KB2763523,[135]: KB2765809,[136]: KB2769369,[137]: KB2770660,[138]: KB2772930,[139]: KB2778344,[140]: KB2778930,[141]: KB2779030,[142]: KB2779562,[143]: KB2785220,[144]: KB2786081,[145]: KB2786400,[146]: KB2789645,[147]: KB2790113,[148]: KB2790655,[149]: KB2791765,[150]: KB2792100,[151]: KB2797052,[152]: KB2798162,[153]: KB2799494,[154]: KB2804579,[155]: KB2806748,[156]: KB2807986,[157]: KB2808679,[158]: KB2808735,[159]: KB2809289,[160]: KB2813170,[161]: KB2813347,[162]: KB2813430,[163]: KB2817183,[164]: KB2820197,[165]: KB2820331,[166]: KB2823324,[167]: KB2830290,[168]: KB2832414,[169]: KB2833946,[170]: KB2834140,[171]: KB2834886,[172]: KB2835361,[173]: KB2836942,[174]: KB2836943,[175]: KB2839894,[176]: KB2840149,[177]: KB2840631,[178]: KB2844286,[179]: KB2849470,[180]: KB2850851,[181]: KB2853587,[182]: KB2853952,[183]: KB2859537,[184]: KB2861855,[185]: KB2862772,[186]: KB2862966,[187]: KB2863058,[188]: KB2868116,[189]: KB2868623,[190]: KB2870699,[191]: KB2872339,[192]: KB2876315,[193]: KB976902,[194]: KB982018"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't need a one-liner solution, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $t="194 Hotfix(s) Installed.,[01]: 982861,[02]: KB259245 ....";
my @numbers=$t=~/KB(\d+)/g;
print join("\n",@numbers);
```

Please note that the first number [01] won't be matched with this regex since the KB prefix is missing, by I guess that was a typo in your post. Otherwise change the matching regex to:

```
my @numbers=$t=~/(\d+)(?:\,|\z)/g;
```

Comment: unfortunately its not a typo, i'm glad you noticed it though. its the output from systeminfo.exe on windows. that particular machine returns that reuslt.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE 'say join " ", /KB(\d+)/g"' file
```